# the correct way to name a system that help find something

Tags: suffixes, names

Hi I want to do a promo spot for a system that helps people find services online,
I want to use the word "Finder", but some people tell me that is only valid when referring to a person not to a "software system" so I am somewhat confused. 
I want to use a sentence like : PlumNet (software system) the finder of plumbers
Would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Locator** is typically the word used for this kind of thing online. *Store locator* is one very common example. See and [here](http://www.safeway.com/shopstores/tools/store-locator.page) and [here](https://www.cvs.com/store-locator/landing) and [here](https://stores.staples.com/search) for examples. That said, a lot of sites do call it a *store finder* instead.

Comment: thanks i really apreciate your answer but I'd really like to know f i can use the word "finder", i found some examples [here](http://forkliftfinder.com.au/) [here](http://www.localplumberfinder.net/) and [here](https://google.org/personfinder) so i want to know if that makes sense for you

Comment: To me, it does. __Locator__ is more common with these kinds of services, but __Finder__ is just fine.